# How do I factor $z^3+2z^2-3z+20$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I just can't factor this equation: $z^3+2z^2-3z+20$

How do you do it? Oh my god!

Comment: Note that $z=-4$ is a root.

Comment: You can look for integer roots, just in case. Here an integer root must be a divisor of $20$, so you have to check $1,2,4,5,10,20$ and the same with minus sign.

Comment: How do you go forward after that?

Comment: Is $z$ real or complex?

Comment: It is Complex...

Answer (score 7):

**A start:** I looked for a root among the divisors of $20$, and found that $z=-4$ is a root.  (Usually, "school" cubics have at least one rational root, and we can use the [Rational Root Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) to find such a root.)

Once we have found a root, *divide* your cubic by $z-(-4)$. We get a quadratic, and factoring quadratics is a familiar problem. In this case, the quadratic will not factor over the integers, or over the reals. But we can use the Quadratic Formula to factor it over the complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

$$z^3+2z^2-3z+20=(z+4)(z^2-2z+5)$$

Comment: Maybe some derivation would be usefull for OP

Comment: After the first comment of Andre I think that's superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

$z^3+2z^2-3z+20=(z+4)(z^2-2z+5)$

So one solution is $z=-4$ and you can find the other solution solving $z^2-2z+5$ and we get $z=1-2i$ and $z=1+2i$..